# citrus waitFor().condition() statement not waiting when used with ftpServer

Tags: citrus-framework

I'm trying to use the citrus-framework to test an integration that writes some files on a FTP server.

I need to wait until some file is uploaded to the ftp (I'm using `waitFor().condition()` statement to accomplish that) and then receive the messages sent and do some assertions.

```
import com.consol.citrus.annotations.CitrusTest;
import com.consol.citrus.condition.Condition;
import com.consol.citrus.context.TestContext;
import com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTestDesigner;
import com.consol.citrus.ftp.server.FtpServer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;

@ActiveProfiles(value = "ftpTest")
@Test
public class FtpTest extends TestNGCitrusTestDesigner {
    @Autowired
    FtpServer ftpServer;
    @Autowired
    TestContext context;

    @CitrusTest(name = "ftpTest")
    public void ftpTest() {

        // here I start my integration that uses a cron to upload the file
        // this code is irrelevant for the example

        Condition waitUntilFileIsUploaded = new Condition() {
            @Override
            public String getName () {
                return "Check files on FTP";
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSatisfied (TestContext testContext){
                return new File("/tmp/foo_dir").listFiles().length != 0;
            }

            @Override
            public String getSuccessMessage (TestContext testContext){
                return "Files found in FTP!";
            }

            @Override
            public String getErrorMessage (TestContext testContext){
                return "No file was found in FTP";
            }
        };

        waitFor().condition(waitUntilFileIsUploaded).seconds(120L).interval(500L);
        ftpServer.createConsumer().receive(context);
    }
}
```

When I try to run this test looks like the `waitFor()` is never executed and `ftpServer.createConsumer().receive(context);` is executed before any file could be uploaded to the FTP.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
ftpTest>TestNGCitrusTest.run:57->TestNGCitrusTest.run:111->TestNGCitrusTestDesigner.invokeTestMethod:73->TestNGCitrusTest.invokeTestMethod:133->ftpTest:49 » ActionTimeout
```

Any idea how I could fix this?
Also any complete example for using FTP Java DSL with Citrus would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use test designer receive method instead of creating the consumer on your own.

```
receive(ftpServer)
       .header("some-header", "some-value")
       .payload("some payload");
```

Only then test designer can arrange the test actions in proper order. This is because test designer constructs the complete test action logic first and execution takes place at the very end of the test method.

As an alternative to that you could also use test runner instead of test designer. The runner will execute each test action immediately giving you the opportunity to add custom statements as you did before.

Comment: Thanks! That was very clarifying, but I have another question... how would you get the uploaded file content? I don't know the filename in advance but I want to set some expectations about the content.
Thanks in advance!